# Http Request Status 400

Tags: android, http

I am trying to send a request to a web service on Android and it returns status 400 I know status 400 means bad request, but I cant see anything wrong. How can I fix this?

Here is my request code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:1455/Android/Android.svc/GetCompanyBusinessAreas2");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company", companhiaIdS));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    //httppost.g
    //httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(companhiaIdS));
    Log.i("Enviando:", nameValuePairs.toString());

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.i("Resposta:", response.getEntity().toString());
    Log.i("status","" +  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

    char[] buffer = new char[(int) responseEntity.getContentLength()];
    Log.i("buffer:","" + responseEntity.getContentLength());

    try {
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
    }

    //FIM DA LIGACAO WCF
    String reply2 = new String(buffer);
    Log.i("teste", reply2);


} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The variable companhiaIdS is a String.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does mean bad request. That probably means the backend is unable to process the request

Comment: can it mean that the service is expecting a diferent type of paramter of what im sending?

Comment: Generally when I'm trying to debug a web server, I execute the request manually via "telnet *server* 80" and typing the http requests by hand. This is slow, but it takes the client app out of the equation and you can determine if the problem is at the server in in the client.

Comment: Next, I write a dummy cgi script at the server that does nothing more than dump its arguments to a file in /tmp and exit. Redirect the client to point at the dummy script instead of the real one, and you can find out for sure what your client is trying to do.

Comment: i found out what it was, its because it is post method so i can only send a list to the web service, so i have to nake a get methos to send only a string